# I need the text from only the first p tags of both lists

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I only want the text first text from both lists. I have added a * next to the ones.

```
<h3 class="icon fa-comment">Colorado Locations</h3>
<section class="lists" id="locate">
    <div class="border" id="ranch">
        <p *class="lists" id="stores">Colorado Ranch Market</p>
        <p class="lists" id="stores">11505 E. Colfax Ave</p>
        <p class="lists" id="stores">Aurora, CO 80010</p>
        <p class="lists" id="stores">PH: 720-343-2195</p>
        <p class="lists" id="stores">FAX: 720-343-2196</p>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
        <p *class="lists" id="stores">Save-A-Lot</p>
        <p class="lists" id="stores">4255 W Florida Ave</p>
        <p class="lists" id="stores">Denver, CO 80219</p>
        <p class="lists" id="stores">PH: 303-935-0880</p>
        <p class="lists" id="stores">FAX: 303-935-4002</p>
    </div>

a = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'border'})[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with a CSS selector:

```
a = soup.select("div.border p:first-child")
```

It returns a list with the first p elements of div with class border.

Answer (score 0):

Another version, using `:nth-of-type()` selector:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print([p.text for p in soup.select('div > p:nth-of-type(1)')])
```

Prints:

```
['Colorado Ranch Market', 'Save-A-Lot']
```

Answer (score 0):

Might as well have the suite of css examples

```
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.border p:nth-child(1)')]
print(items)
```

Something you wouldn't want to do (particular just to example html given):

```
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('#locate p:nth-child(3n+1):nth-child(odd)')]
```